# How to generate reports from a plumber API that was deployed in Docker through Gitlab

Tags: r, docker, api, gitlab, plumber

I've deployed a simple plumber API that accepts only two get commands.

I am relatively new to the subject, so I wondered what is the simplest way to answer the 3 questions below:

1. What was the API response?
2. How many hits were performed?
3. What were the parameters passed in the two get commands?

I apologize for summarising 3 questions in one, but I believe that the 3 questions need only 1 answer.
Here is a simplified sample of my R code.

```
#* @param msg
#* @get /echo
function(msg="") {
  list(msg = paste0("The message is: ", msg))
}

# Load the model
my_model <- readRDS("my_model.rds")

#predicitons on the model

#* @param P1
#* @param P2
#* @param P2
#* @get /predict

predict <- function(# here is the function that return the prediction)
```

Is there a way to perform it by another get command? I'm using Kibana/Discover- Elastic but I'm not finding a way to use it so I can answer the questions above.

Comment: Unless gitlab is actually *serving* the R API somehow, I don't see how [tag:gitlab] is appropriate. That is, whether an API is deployed manually from the R console or automatically in from `.gitlab-ci.yml` (or similar) is unimportant, since what you need occurs after gitlab is out of the picture.

Comment: What is your serving platform? If you are using RStudio Connect (RSC), then they have an API for access API hits which will give you the plumber app (not individual endpoints) and the userid (if auth is being doing); it does not as far as I know report the endpoint itself nor the arguments to it (that would be useful to me as well). If you are not using RSC and instead hosting directly in a docker/R container, then I suspect you need to generate your own logs, as I believe `plumber` does not log.

Comment: Logging is mentioned in [*Hosting*](https://www.rplumber.io/articles/hosting.html#logs-and-management-1) as well as [*Tips & Tricks*](https://www.rplumber.io/articles/tips-and-tricks.html#print-debugging-1), though only to mention that `plumber::run()` prints out certain things on stdout "in a debugging environment" (I think that means only when interactive).

Comment: Thanks, everyone for your comments. I'm not using RSC, the API was deployed in an internal server. I'm just trying to figuring basic things like generating those numbers to have a better understanding of what the users are requesting.

Comment: Yes, that's a fine way to deploy it, and unfortunately not full of built-in logging or metrics. Unless I'm mistaken, you need to do logging yourself; that's a two-tiered problem: first, update your plumber API endpoints to provide individual (and standardized for your needs) logging; second, figure out how to automate getting docker's stdout into a consumable/stored location.